# Flutter, Chat with two different apps

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm very new to `flutter` and I want to know if there is any logic to the solution, a question that comes to mind if I have merchant and customer apps, so every flutter app has its own google service `json` file from `firebase` library, so merchant app id is : `com.myapp.merchant` and customer app id is : `com.myapp.customer`.
So I want the customer to be able to chat with the merchant and vice versa
so logically using firebase database is this possible? How can I do it, just explain and may no need for writing any code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more):

> A Firebase project is the top-level entity for Firebase. In a project, you create Firebase apps by registering your iOS, Android, or web apps. After you register your apps with Firebase, you can add the Firebase SDKs for any number of Firebase products, like Analytics, Cloud Firestore, Performance Monitoring, or Remote Config.

Therefore, if both apps belong to the same project, then yes, the apps can access the same database.

You are able to use [multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects) in your app, however, it's less straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

you can just link them to the same database while initiating FlutterFire-CLI.

It will generate two same google-service.json and related accounts file automatically.